# Oracle - Date not between Multiple Rows

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a table with start and end dates. I want to make sure that no new dates will overlap any of the periods defined between the start and end date. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

You could check for existing rows for that new date before inserting:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM THE_TABLE 
  WHERE  (
    ? BETWEEN START_DATE AND END_DATE
  OR 
    ? BETWEEN START_DATE AND END_DATE 
  OR
    START_DATE BETWEEN ? AND ?
  ) AND ROWNUM<2
```

(where the ? are the start and end dates of the new period to be tested).

You probably need to synchronize this (for example with a LOCK TABLE) to avoid race conditions.

Comment: that looks great.. but one scenerio would still be not handled... imagine that in the table the period between 1st Aug and 31st Aug is taken, if a new date between 1st july and 30 september is entered, it would still be considered as valid where actually an error should errupt..

Comment: True. Added another case for that. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Further to what Thilo said, the following must also be handled

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM THE_TABLE 
  WHERE  (
    DATE_1 BETWEEN START_DATE AND END_DATE
  OR 
    DATE_2 BETWEEN START_DATE AND END_DATE 
  OR
    START_DATE BETWEEN DATE_1 AND DATE_2
  OR
    END_DATE BETWEEN DATE_1 AND DATE_2
  ) 
AND ROWNUM<2
```

Comment: I am thinking that the fourth clause is redundant.